# java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: PBE AlgorithmParameters not available

Tags: java, docker, ssl, openssl

I have a java 8 app in a docker container which connects to a kafka cluster using SSL keystore (PKCS12 format). The app is deployed in K8s cluster. The app worked before, but now it throws the following error:

```
java.io.IOException: parseAlgParameters failed: PBE AlgorithmParameters not available

java.io.IOException: parseAlgParameters failed: PBE AlgorithmParameters not available
        at sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.parseAlgParameters(PKCS12KeyStore.java:828)
        at sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(PKCS12KeyStore.java:2047)
        at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445)
        at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Main.java:835)
        at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Main.java:378)
        at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Main.java:371)
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: PBE AlgorithmParameters not available
        at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:159)
        at java.security.Security.getImpl(Security.java:695)
        at java.security.AlgorithmParameters.getInstance(AlgorithmParameters.java:146)
        at sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.parseAlgParameters(PKCS12KeyStore.java:822)
```

I noticed that if I log into K8s pod, and run the keytool command ( keytool -list -v  -keystore keystore.jks -storetype PKCS12), I get the same error.

I tried using different java 8 images (eclipse-temurin:8u372-b07-jre, openjdk:8-jre-slim, openjdk:8-jre-slim-stretch), but get same error on java app and with keytool command.

The K8s pod is a 3.10.0-1160.59.1.e17.x86_64 with no FIPS.

I regenerated the p12 and jks based on root, key and cert pems using openssl 1.1 and 3.1.1

If I build the docker image and run container locally on mac docker desktop, the keytool command works.

The cksum on K8s configmap jks file is same compared to local jks file.

If I look at p12 or jks using openssl (locally), it contains:

```
PKCS7 Data
Shrouded Keybag: PBES2, PBKDF2, AES-256-CBC, Iteration 2048, PRF hmacWithSHA256
```

Please advise what else I can try.
Thanks

**UPDATE**: I redeployed again with OpenSSL v3 certs, and it suddenly worked. Not sure previous deployment was wrong, or some environment update.

Comment: show us kubectl logs tail output.